# How to store private key on a VPS in a secure manner?

Tags: security, private-key, keystore, server-side, keymanagement

I have a service which will interract with my smart contract which will include money transfer. For this reason, a private key of the owner or deployer of a smart contract will have to be store on a server, correct? How would I store them in a more or less secure manner?

Note that I'm not looking for a bullet-proof and, hence, complex solution. Rather, something simple and yet the one that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this resource to get an idea to store private keys via VPS in a secure manner:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240878/is-this-a-good-practice-for-storing-private-keys

Comment: I can find a hundred of such links myself. I've asked a concreate question